# AWS Lambda - Python 3.8 how to write to CSV file with more than one column and multiple lines?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to write to a CSV file named, Key='csv/ccc_master_circuit.csv', and my bucket name in S3 is cenicbucket1. I am able to write to the ccc_master_circuit.csv without errors if I only have one column in the client.put_object statement.

It's only when I attempt to write with more than one column do I get the error below. I am also trying to write more than one line in the CSV file.

Here's the Lambda run error (after Invoke).

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 135)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 135\n        client.put_object(Body=ccckeyid prjstatus cenic_status cenic_internal telco cenic_imp_jira order_date deliv_date cpe_date ops_ready mig_complete disco_date usg_track_sw crickusage Project_Value_HiLvl cirid, Bucket='cenicbucket1', Key='csv/ccc_master_circuit.csv')\n"
  ]
}
```

My Lambda function is running Python 3.8 code.  I also need to write multiple lines as def create_csv runs iterable called within a for-loop.

**A Quick Job-Flow Synopsis**

1. **def main calls** def bump_through_master(sheet)
2. **def bump_through_master(sheet)** reads Smartsheet file one row at a time and assigns variables (for-loop).
3. **bump_through_master(sheet)** passes variables collected from the Smartsheet row and calls the **def create_csv** function.
4. **def create_csv** writes variables to the CSV cenic_master_circuit in the S3 bucket named, "cenicbucket1".  *This is where I am getting the Lambda error.*
5. Each time **def create_csv** is called, a new line should be appended to the CSV file cenic_master_circuit.

- Smartsheet is like an Excel file on the cloud.  It's only mentioned here for completeness.*

```
def create_csv(ccckeyid, prjstatus, cenic_status, cenic_internal, telco, cenic_imp_jira, order_date, deliv_date, cpe_date, ops_ready, mig_complete, disco_date, usg_track_sw, crickusage, Project_Value_HiLvl, cirid):
    print("Creating CSV...")
    
    try:
      encoded_ccckeyid = ccckeyid.encode("utf-8")
    except:
      print("encoded_ccckeyid is NonType.  Skipping ...")
      return
      
    encoded_prjstatus = prjstatus.encode("utf-8")
    encoded_cenic_status = cenic_status.encode("utf-8")
    encoded_cenic_internal = cenic_internal.encode("utf-8")
    encoded_telco = telco.encode("utf-8")
    encoded_cenic_imp_jira = cenic_imp_jira.encode("utf-8")
    encoded_order_date = order_date.encode("utf-8")
    encoded_deliv_date = deliv_date.encode("utf-8")
    encoded_cpe_date = cpe_date.encode("utf-8")
    encoded_ops_ready = ops_ready.encode("utf-8")
    encoded_mig_complete = mig_complete.encode("utf-8")
    encoded_disco_date = disco_date.encode("utf-8")
    encoded_usg_track_sw = usg_track_sw.encode("utf-8") 
    encoded_crickusage = crickusage.encode("utf-8") 
    encoded_Project_Value_HiLvl = Project_Value_HiLvl.encode("utf-8")
    encoded_cirid = cirid.encode("utf-8")
        
    #Create CSV file in S3 bucket
    ccckeyid = encoded_ccckeyid
    prjstatus = encoded_prjstatus
    cenic_status = encoded_cenic_status
    cenic_internal = encoded_cenic_internal
    telco = encoded_telco
    cenic_imp_jira = encoded_cenic_imp_jira
    order_date = encoded_order_date
    deliv_date = encoded_deliv_date
    cpe_date = encoded_cpe_date
    ops_ready = encoded_ops_ready
    mig_complete = encoded_mig_complete
    disco_date = encoded_disco_date
    usg_track_sw = encoded_usg_track_sw
    crickusage =  encoded_crickusage
    Project_Value_HiLvl = encoded_Project_Value_HiLvl
    cirid = encoded_cirid
    bucket_name = "cenicbucket1"
    file_name = "ccc_master_circuit.csv"
    lambda_path = "/tmp/" + file_name
    s3_path = "/csv/" + file_name
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    client.put_object(Body=ccckeyid prjstatus cenic_status cenic_internal telco cenic_imp_jira order_date deliv_date cpe_date ops_ready mig_complete disco_date usg_track_sw crickusage Project_Value_HiLvl cirid, Bucket='cenicbucket1', Key='csv/ccc_master_circuit.csv')

def bump_through_master(sheet):
  
  x = 0
  
  for row in sheet.rows:
    x += 1

    #************ CCC Key ID *********
    ccckeyid = row.get_cell("CCC Key ID").value     
    if ccckeyid == "None":
        continue
    print("ccckeyid", ccckeyid)
    
    prjstatus = row.get_cell("CCC Project Status").value
    
    prjstatus = clean_fld(prjstatus)
    if isBlank(prjstatus):
      prjstatus = ""
      
      
    print("Record [", x, "]", " prjstatus", prjstatus)

    #***********  CENIC Status ************
    cenic_status = row.get_cell("CENIC Status Update").value    
    cenic_status = clean_fld(cenic_status)
    if isBlank(cenic_status):
      cenic_status = ""
    
    #***********  CENIC Internal Status ***
    cenic_internal = row.get_cell("CENIC Internal Status").value
    cenic_internal = clean_fld(cenic_internal)
    if isBlank(cenic_internal):
      cenic_internal = ""
         
    telco = row.get_cell("Telco").value
    telco = clean_fld(telco)
    if isBlank(telco):
      telco = ""
          
    cenic_imp_jira = row.get_cell("CENIC Implement Jira #").value        
    cenic_imp_jira = clean_fld(cenic_imp_jira)
    if isBlank(cenic_imp_jira):
      cenic_imp_jira = ""
          
    order_date = row.get_cell("Order Date - Text").value
    order_date = clean_fld(order_date)
    order_date = fix_date(order_date, ccckeyid)
    if isBlank(order_date):
      order_date = ""
          
    deliv_date = row.get_cell("Delivery Date - Text").value
    deliv_date = clean_fld(deliv_date)
    deliv_date = fix_date(deliv_date, ccckeyid)
    if isBlank(deliv_date):
      deliv_date = ""
          
    cpe_date = row.get_cell("CPE Date - Text").value
    cpe_date = clean_fld(cpe_date)
    cpe_date = fix_date(cpe_date, ccckeyid)
    if isBlank(cpe_date):
      cpe_date = ""
          
    ops_ready = row.get_cell("Ops Ready Date - Text").value
    ops_ready = clean_fld(ops_ready)
    ops_ready = fix_date(ops_ready, ccckeyid)
    if isBlank(ops_ready):
      ops_ready = ""
          
    mig_complete = row.get_cell("Migration Complete Date - Text").value
    mig_complete = clean_fld(mig_complete)
    mig_complete = fix_date(mig_complete, ccckeyid)
    if isBlank(mig_complete):
      mig_complete = ""
          
    disco_date = row.get_cell("Disconnect Date - Text").value
    disco_date = clean_fld(disco_date)
    disco_date = fix_date(disco_date, ccckeyid)
    if isBlank(disco_date):
      disco_date = ""
              
    crickusage = row.get_cell("Cricket Usage Report").value    
    crickusage = clean_fld(crickusage)
    if isBlank(crickusage):
      crickusage = ""
              
    usg_track_sw = row.get_cell("Usage Tracking").value    
    usg_track_sw = clean_fld(usg_track_sw)
    if isBlank(usg_track_sw):
      usg_track_sw = ""
              
    cirid = row.get_cell("CIRCUIT ID").value
    cirid = clean_fld(cirid)
    if isBlank(cirid):
      cirid = ""
              
    Project_Value_HiLvl = row.get_cell("Project Value HiLvl").value
    Project_Value_HiLvl = clean_fld(Project_Value_HiLvl)          
    if isBlank(Project_Value_HiLvl):
      Project_Value_HiLvl = ""
              
    debugprints(ccckeyid, prjstatus, cenic_status, cenic_internal, telco, cenic_imp_jira, order_date, deliv_date, cpe_date, ops_ready, mig_complete, disco_date, usg_track_sw, crickusage, Project_Value_HiLvl, cirid)
    create_csv(ccckeyid, prjstatus, cenic_status, cenic_internal, telco, cenic_imp_jira, order_date, deliv_date, cpe_date, ops_ready, mig_complete, disco_date, usg_track_sw, crickusage, Project_Value_HiLvl, cirid)
    
def main():

  smartsheet,SHEET_ID = import_simple_smartsheet_env()

  sheet = smartsheet.sheets.get(SHEET_ID)

  bump_through_master(sheet)
```

**A Bonus Question!**

Is there a way to delete the csv/ccc_master_circuit.csv within my Lambda/Python code?  I need to do this before I run the function so I have a "clean" ccc_master_circuit.csv where no previous written data exists each at the beginning of my function call.  The delete CSV file must happen at the top of the function, before I write new data.

Comment: python 3.8?? Python 8 isn't a thing

Comment: Sorry, should be Python 3.8